# Positioning dynamically created control that overlaps another control in a resource dialog causes odd behaviour

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to create a dynamic custom control on a resource dialog at runtime which overlaps an already existing control.  However, when I do that, it causes a weird artifact.

If I position the new control after the other control in the z-order, my dynamic control is drawn over top of the resource control, as I expected.  However, if I click on a spot that is shared between the two controls, it will select the resource control.

If I position the new control before the other control in the z-order, my dynamic control is drawn over by the resource control, again as expected.  However, if I again click on the spot that is shared between them, it will select the new control.

What I would have expected is that the control in the top of the z-order would have any clicks directed at them.  The actual results are counter intuitive.  Why is this happening?

As a code example, I've created an MFC dialog application, where the dialog useds two listboxes to remove any issues with any custom control errors.  One listbox is added to the resource with id `IDC_LIST1` with member variable name `m_dlgResCtrl`.  The second has the member variable name `m_dlgAddedCtrl`.  The following code is added to the `OnInitDialog()` member function:

```
CRect rect;
m_dlgResCtrl.GetWindowRect(rect);
ScreenToClient(rect);
rect += CPoint(20, 20);
m_dlgAddedCtrl.Create(LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    , rect, this, IDC_LIST1 + 1);
m_dlgAddedCtrl.SetFont(GetFont());

// place before resource control in z-order
//m_dlgAddedCtrl.SetWindowPos(m_dlgResCtrl.GetWindow(GW_HWNDPREV), 0, 0, 0, 0
    , SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
// place after resource control in z-order
m_dlgAddedCtrl.SetWindowPos(&m_dlgResCtrl, 0, 0, 0, 0
    , SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

// added some text to show overlap
m_dlgResCtrl.AddString(L"Res ctrl");
m_dlgAddedCtrl.AddString(L"Added ctrl");
```

When placed after res control:

[image: When placed after res control]

After clicking on shared space:

[image: After clicking on shared space]

When placed before res control:

[image: When placed before res control]

After clicking on shared space:

[image: After clicking on shared space]

NOTE: this behavour is not limited to dynamic controls.  Just moving the `OK` button control to overlap the `Cancel` button control shows the same problem.  The `OK` has a z-order number of 1 and the `Cancel` of 2.  The `Cancel` shows over top of the `OK` but when clicked in the overlapping region, the `OK` is the one that is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing z-order and drawing order. They are not necessarily related.

A window that is *before* another window in the z-order, is *above* the other window. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633509(v=vs.85).aspx).

So this code actually positions `m_dlgAddedCtrl` *below* `m_dlgResCtrl`:

```
// place after resource control in z-order
m_dlgAddedCtrl.SetWindowPos(&m_dlgResCtrl, 0, 0, 0, 0
    , SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

This code actually positions `m_dlgAddedCtrl` *above* `m_dlgResCtrl`:

```
// place before resource control in z-order
//m_dlgAddedCtrl.SetWindowPos(m_dlgResCtrl.GetWindow(GW_HWNDPREV), 0, 0, 0, 0
    , SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Considering this, the **click behaviour in both cases is correct**. In the overlapping area, the topmost child window receives the mouse click and gets focused.

Only the **drawing order appears incorrect**. It may come as a surprise that Windows doesn't automatically respect the z-order when drawing child windows! It just sends `WM_PAINT` messages to all child windows with a non-empty update region which are then free to draw over each other in whatever order the `WM_PAINT` messages arrive.

To fix that, simply add the [`WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx) style to each child window that may overlap other child windows:

From MSDN:

> when a particular
>   child window receives a WM_PAINT message, the WS_CLIPSIBLINGS style
>   clips all other overlapping child windows out of the region of the
>   child window to be updated. If WS_CLIPSIBLINGS is not specified and
>   child windows overlap, it is possible, when drawing within the client
>   area of a child window, to draw within the client area of a
>   neighboring child window.

Comment: Ah, I see. I would have expected them to be the same as that would have been more intuitive.  Why would MS go the non-intuitive route?  Was there method to their madness?  Or just a random/poor design choice?

Comment: I also didn't realize that 1 was higher than 2 in the z-order.  Good to know.  I would have thought that the paint messages would have iterated from 1 .. _N_, resulting in the higher number to be higher in the z-order.  (I use 1 only because the dialog editor uses it)

Comment: "_Why would MS go the non-intuitive route?_" - Propably because of efficiency. Back it in the days when the Windows GUI was invented, one had to save computing resources everywhere. Overlapping child windows are not very common, so it would be a waste of resources to always consider the z-order for drawing.

Comment: But there would have to be some order in which the messages were sent. How could sending messages to a pseudo-random order be more efficient?

Comment: It's not a random order. When all child windows are invalidated, the system propably redraws them in z-order. This can be seen from your screenshots. The topmost window gets redrawn first, then the next lower window gets redrawn and paints over the topmost window. But if only *some* windows are invalidated, only these will be redrawn and the result may appear out of order.

Comment: That's exactly my point.  Why not redraw in reverse z-order, thus removing this issue all together?  Can that actually be slower?  At worst, I can only see this as taking the same amount of time while being more intuitive.

Comment: But then they would have to redraw all windows on top of the invalidated window aswell. Not very efficient.

Comment: That's what clipping is for.  Also, this wouldn't be an issue most of the time as most controls are not overlapping.  Thus, no inefficiencies unless needed.

Comment: They still would have to calculate which (if any) controls are overlapping. And most likely for this reason they didn't choose to: "_most controls are not overlapping_". Anyway, while the "why" is surely interesting, we can only guess. We either live with that or choose a more "intuitive" framework like WPF.